# How to create a Nav menu li using javascript? And how to scroll smoothly to section after clicking the menu option?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a nav menu with 4 options using only Javascript. I'm trying to insert it into a 'ul' with the id of "navbar__list" and I want to create the li with classes and ids all through JS. This is what I've made so far, but I know my code seems repetitive and I'm not sure how to make it more concise.

```
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navList = document.getElementById("navbar__list");

//Attempt to build the Nav Menu
const navItem1 = document.createElement("a");
navItem1.classList.add("menu-items");
navItem1.setAttribute("id", "menu-1");
navItem1.innerText = "Section 1";
navItem1.href = "#section1";
navList.appendChild(navItem1);

const navItem2 = document.createElement("a");
navItem2.classList.add("menu-items");
navItem2.setAttribute("id", "menu-2");
navItem2.innerText = "Section 2";
navItem2.href = "#section2";
navList.appendChild(navItem2);

const navItem3 = document.createElement("a");
navItem3.classList.add("menu-items");
navItem3.setAttribute("id", "menu-3");
navItem3.innerText = "Section 3";
navItem3.href = "#section3";
navList.appendChild(navItem3);

const navItem4 = document.createElement("a");
navItem4.classList.add("menu-items");
navItem4.setAttribute("id", "menu-4");
navItem4.innerText = "Section 4";
navItem4.href = "#section4";
navList.appendChild(navItem4);
```

I also want to create a scroll effect, so whenever I click on the menu option, it will scroll smoothly to the section in my HTML. Each section is label Section1 - Section4.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, You can use the following code instead of repetition and it does the same task

```js
const navList = document.getElementById("navbar__list");

for(let i=1; i<5; i++){
    const navItem = document.createElement("a");
    navItem.classList.add("menu-items");
    navItem.setAttribute("id", `menu-${i}`);
    navItem.innerText = `Section ${i}`;
    navItem.href = `#menu-${i}`;
    navList.appendChild(navItem);
}
```

I believe this is going to solve the first issue.

Secondly, for smooth scrolling. In your css ass

```css
html,body{
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

for more information about smooth scrolling check this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp

Comment: is there a way to implement the scroll effect with Javascript? Like with an addEventListener?

Comment: You can check the above link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp.
At the bottom, there's a section to understand how you can achieve this using javascript and it's compatible with all browsers

Answer (score 0):

The above approach is very correct but I used a different approach to accomplish this.

I used array to store the menu items and then used forEach loop through the array to create the anchor elements and add them to the ul list.

```
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("header");
const navList = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const items = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3", "Section 4"];

items.forEach((item, i) => {
    const el = document.createElement("a");
    el.innerText = item;
    el.classList.add("menu-items");
    el.setAttribute("id", `menu-${i + 1}`);
    el.href = `#section${i + 1}`;
    navList.appendChild(el);
});
```

Checkout the codepen link to have a look:
https://codepen.io/burhanmm/pen/vYOqQdb